# how to remove first div from a html page include by iframe using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I add a html page in my CI project using **iframe**. Now i want to **remove first div** from included page. there is no id for that div. i write a jquery code but it **removes whole iframe**. here it is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").load(function(){
    //$('div:first').remove(); 
      $("body").find("div:first-child").remove();   
  });
});
```

html

```
<div class="span12">
                <iframe id="patrolIframe" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" 
                src="http://...../map.html"></iframe>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("iframe").load(function(){
   $("body",this).find("div:first-child").remove();   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").load(function(){
      $('div')[0].remove(); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Does the DOM api have a `remove()` method?

Comment: I know about the jquery method. I wasn't sure if [0] returned a jQuery object or a plain dom element.

Comment: @ moddasir your div is inside the iframe or html...??

Comment: @Prasath I already mention. I want to Changing Elements in an iFrame. I load a html page from different domain and i want to remove its first div.

Comment: Use this.$('div')[0].remove();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").load(function(){
    //$('div:first').remove(); 
      $(this).find("div:first-child").remove();   
  });
});
```

You $("body") selector selects the body of the page your jquery is loaded in, that is, the whole page. Im guessing your iframe is inside the first div of that page, so it gets removed. I dont use iframes, but i assume the $(this) on that case is refering to the iframe so it should work.